# Prove that if C is a regular language, then the language $\{x x^R : x\in C\}$ is context-free

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata

> Let $C$ be a regular language. Prove that the language $D = \{x x^R : x\in C\}$ is context-free.

It's clearly important that $C$ is regular; if the hypothesis were weakened to C being context-free, then we would have the counterexample $C = \{0^n 1^n : n\ge 0\}, D = \{0^n 1^{2n} 0^n:n\ge0\},$ which isn't context-free.

Assume $G_C$ is a context-free grammar for $C$ in Chomsky normal form. I don't think that just replacing every rule of the form $X\mapsto YZ$ in $G_C$ with $X\mapsto YZZY$ will produce the required language; rather it likely produces something like $\{x y^R :x,y \in C\} = C\cap C^R,$ which is clearly regular.

Maybe some closure properties might be useful? For instance, if $A$ is a context free language and $B$ is a regular language, then $A\cap B$ is context free. I know $CC$ is a regular language, and I know that the set of all palindromes of a regular language is a context-free language. But I don't think $D$ is the set of all palindromes of $CC$.

Comment: A related question, which has a similar solution: [Why does $A(L)=\{w_1w_2 \mid |w_1|=|w_2|,  w_1,w^R_2 \in L \}$ generate a context free language for regular $L$?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/1628/4287)

Comment: This is the special case of [$\{xx^R \mid x\in L_1, x^R\in L_2\}$ is context-free if $L_1, L_2$ are regular languagese](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11240/xxr-mid-x-in-l-1-xr-in-l-2-is-context-free-if-l-1-l-2-are-regular-l), where $L_2=L_1^R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that every finite state automaton can be changed into a rightlinear grammar which has productions like $X\to aY $ and $X\to \varepsilon$.

Your language can be generated using the same technique, but with linear productions which have the form $X\to aYa $ or $X\to \varepsilon$.